# Why "return o" in this simple example?

Tags: javascript, return

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function createPerson (name){
var o = new Object();
o.name = name;

return o;
};
var person1 = createPerson ("Nicholas");
alert(person1.name);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Why do we have to

> return o

?
What does "return" mean?

Comment: When you're asking questions about books, please include information about the work. It helps people help you, as well as correctly attributing the code. In this case, it's from *Professional JavaScript for Web Developers, Second Edition* by Nicholas C. Zakas (Wrox, 2009), page 152.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` is a JavaScript keyword that causes the *function* it's placed in to exit with the specified value (called the "return value").

In this case, it causes the `createPerson()` function to come to an end, returning the `o` object to the *caller* of the function.

The `o` object, once returned from `createPerson()`, then gets assigned to the `person1` variable.

So the net result is that control flow starts here

```
var person1 = createPerson ("Nicholas");
```

then jumps into the `createPerson()` function, which creates a new object representing a person with the name "Nicholas", then returns it, which brings the execution back to that line, with `person1` getting the newly created person that the function returned.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know what `return` means then I suggest reading just about any book on procedural, functional or object oriented programming before you write anything in any language and get into trouble.

You can start from [Eloquent JavaScript: A Modern Introduction to Programming](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) 
by Marijn Haverbeke, available online.

Answer (score 1):

The `return` keyword is the basic mechanism of getting a result out of a function. It sounds like you don't understand the basics. Have a read over [`return` @ MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return). Another helpful MDC page: [Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)!

Comment: At first i thought he didnt understand what o was and somewhat had it mixed up with 0. But i guess you are right, i think this is a way to broad question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. This is like a walk-through of the code. START reading from **Line 6**.

```
1: function createPerson (name){ //name will now be "Nicholas"
2: var o = new Object();//created a new object, store it in o
3: o.name = name;//added a name property assign name to it (would be Nicholas)
4: return o; //<<return o BACK to line 6.
5: };
6: var person1 = createPerson ("Nicholas");//<<goes to Line 1.
//BACK here person1 have the value of o
7: alert(person1.name); //In line 3 we did o.name = "Nicholas"
//since person1 is equal to o this will popup an alert saying Nicholas.
```

I more or less simplified it being less strict/formal with the words I used.